# Php downloading all file types

Tags: php, download, mime-types

i am just wondering if there is a way of setting up different "content-type" when downloading through php? like .mp3 AND .pdf etc.. instead of having to specify just one file type. My problem is that i have 2 file types to be downloaded, one type is pdf and the other type is mp3, but if i change the "content-type" to audio/mpeg, then it doesn't show the extension for the .pdf... i hope you understand? please help!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean your user is downloading some content that's sent from a PHP script, which is also sending the `Content-type` HTTP header, can you not set that header with a different value for each type of file ?

Something like this *(pseudo-code)* :

```
if (file is a PDF) {
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
} else if (file is a MP3) {
    header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
}
```

And a "default" case might be useful, if you also have some other files you have not thought about just yet.

Answer (score 0):

This function works great for me:

```
function Download($path, $speed = null)
{
    if (is_file($path) === true)
    {
        set_time_limit(0);

        while (ob_get_level() > 0)
        {
            ob_end_clean();
        }

        $size = sprintf('%u', filesize($path));
        $speed = (is_null($speed) === true) ? $size : intval($speed) * 1024;

        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($path) . '"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

        for ($i = 0; $i <= $size; $i = $i + $speed)
        {
            echo file_get_contents($path, false, null, $i, $speed);

            while (ob_get_level() > 0)
            {
                ob_end_clean();
            }

            flush();
            sleep(1);
        }

        exit();
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can also optionally specify the max speed at which the file is delivered.

Comment: for me, octet-stream does nothing, it sends a file without extension, and im using firefox developer edition